# SCP is creating two directories (One in the other) with same name, where it is supposed to create only one

Tags: linux, bash, automation, scripting, scp

This is the bash script I'm trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
password = SECRET
sshpass -p $password ssh root@destination_ip "mkdir -p /PVs"
sshpass -p $password scp -r /path/to/clear-nginx-deployment/ root@destination_ip:/PVs/
```

Basically, I'm trying to copy my local directory `clear-nginx-deployment` into the remote directory `/PVs` as it is.

The result I get on the destination machine, after running the script:

`/PVs/clear-nginx-deployment/clear-nginx-deployment/content.html`

The result which I expect:

`/PVs/clear-nginx-deployment/content.html`

Please help to get through this.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: ```sshpass -p $password scp -r /path/to/clear-nginx-deployment root@destination_ip:/PVs/```

Comment: what does `ll /path/to/clear-nginx-deployment/` show?